# Sendgrid autogenerate "View in Browser" for ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

Can Sendgrid generate `[weblink]` and auto 'View in Browser' for ActionMailer e-mails likewise he does with Marketing Emails?

I'm using sendgrid free plan in heroku in a Rails application.

Comment: I guess, no. It won't create a web view for this. Did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the View In Browser function is only available for messages sent through the Marketing Email Service, since those are the only messages kept on the SendGrid server.